# How to use @UtilityClass lombok annotation on inner class in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, inner-classes, lombok

I have a class where `@UtilityClass` annotation on class C and class D gives error in eclipse IDE but works fine with IntelliJ

> @UtilityClass automatically makes the class static, however, this
> class cannot be made static.

Not able to use @UtilityClass annotation on class C and class D. `Lombok v1.18.20 "Envious Ferret"` is installed.

```
 @UtilityClass
    public class A {
    
        @UtilityClass
        public class B {
    
            public final String name = "name";
            public final String id = "id";
    
            @UtilityClass
            public class C {
    
                public final String OVER = "over.draft";
                public final String ADD = "add.draft";
            }
    
            @UtilityClass
            public class D {
    
                public final String OVER = "over.published";
                public final String ADD = "add.published";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check if:
- you have the same java version selected
- the same language level selected These are the two most common issue with lombok.

Comment: Have you tried making the inner class static? I know the annotation is already supposed to do that, but maybe there is an ordering issue or something? Please try making A and B static, and see if there is still a problem with C and D afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug if it is not working in eclipse and working in Intellij.

The doc for `@UtilityClass` states that all methods, inner classes and fields in the class would be marked as `static`, if we use this annotation. Going by that, class `B` should become `static`.

Now looking at the code (`lombok.javac.JavacNode`) from where the error mentioned in question is thrown, the code comment says that:

```
// It might be an inner class. This is okay, but only if it is / can be a
// static inner class. Thus, all of its parents have to be static inner classes
// until the top-level.
```

So if `@UtilityClass` annotation is used on class `C` then class `B` should be `static` for it to work.

Since class `A` is annotated with `@UtilityClass`, class `B` should have become `static`, but may be, it is not recognized as `static` during the above mentioned validation.

To fix this, you need to manually add `static` to class `B`. (Project build might also be required).

(You may also log a bug in the lombok github page)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JDK version isn't above version 8(1.8), cause looks like there is a [bug](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3097) in lombok, that @UtilityClass doesn't make inner classes static when JDK 9 or higher

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1720.html#support-for-kotlin-k2-compiler-plugins

Comment: Lombok 1.18.24 contains the fix https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3097#issuecomment-1103976866